# Show first post where select field is true in ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So I have a WordPress post loop. These posts have a few custom fields from the plugin 'Advanced Custom Fields (ACF)', including a select field named 'homepage'. This select field can be checked when I want the post to show on the homepage. The homepage has a loop for 1 post.

So I tried using an if statement:

```
<?php if(get_field('homepage_yn') == true){ ?>
<!-- code here -->
<?php } ?>
```

But ofcourse, this only works on the first post that is passed. But if this post has a checked value of 'false', the loop doesn't go further in search of a post that has a checked value of 'true'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get you correctly , this query will give you the required row ,

```
SELECT * FROM 
wp_posts A inner join wp_postmeta B
ON A.id = B.post_id
WHERE B.meta_key= 'homepage_yn'
ORDER BY post_date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Okay, so I have these lines of code to create the loop:

Comment: `<?php $loop = new WP_Query("showposts=1"); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>`

Comment: Okay, so I didn't use the exact code you send me, but this code sure helped me with it, so I could solve it! Thanks so much!